# Escape Sequence of bell alert not working in java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, cmd

I am using escape sequence `(JAVA)` "\a" or '\a', then it simply gives me errors...

My code...

```
class Bell{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("\a");
    }
}
```

I don't know why it keeps on saying:

```
Bell.java:4: error: illegal escape character
        System.out.println("\a");
                             ^
1 error
```

When I use `'\a'` instead of `"\a"`, again it shows me error:

```
Bell.java:4: error: illegal escape character
        System.out.println('\a');
                             ^
Bell.java:4: error: unclosed character literal
        System.out.println('\a');
                           ^
Bell.java:4: error: unclosed character literal
        System.out.println('\a');
                              ^
3 errors
```

Occurs in both VS Code and CMD but it gives error.
Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

My JDK version is `15.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such escape sequence in Java.

See the [JLS section 3.10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for which escape sequences are valid. There is no "single-character-after-backslash" escape sequence for the bell character.

If you want to represent U+0007 in a string or character literal, use `\u0007`.

Comment: Okay! Your way works. Shockingly my book says that there IS an escape sequence of '`\a'` which produces a beep sound...

Comment: @UtkarshSahu: Which book is that, out of interest? (It wouldn't be the first error in a technical book, of course...)

Comment: It is `Computer Applications : A Textbook for Class X (ICSE Edition)`

Comment: @UtkarshSahu: And it's *definitely* referring to Java, not some other language where `\a` is a valid escape sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is a book of pure java (but for **beginners** ) and some concept of object orientation. It supports `BlueJ` and so I think they have given `\a` as one of the escape sequences... Well maybe it works on BlueJ only since there are many more things which work on BlueJ but not on other compilers...
For eg: Parameters for method main() is not necessary when using BlueJ.

Comment: @UtkarshSahu: That's more of a "starting the program" aspect - it's not a core part of the language. I'd really *hope* that BlueJ doesn't allow invalid Java like that.

Comment: @UtkarshSahu, as someone who read the book 11 years back, it's indeed wrong. '\a' exists in C, and I think the authors blindly copied it. It's a high-school book, after all; not a lot of fact-checking goes there. But I'm surprised that the mistake exists 11 years later.